# Graphical screen error whenever I boot Linux

Tags: linux, boot, dual-boot, login, graphics

For some time now, whenever I boot into my Linux, this graphical error appears at the login screen. I have to log in and switch to an F1-6 terminal and then go back to the GUI to get it fixed. If I do that and then log in, sometimes it gets stuck at a black screen with a prompt.

Linux 5.10.6-arch1-1
  Arcolinux + i3wm
  Dual boot
  ThinkPad T470S

[image: graphical error after boot]

Comment: Looks like some kind of problem with the GPU driver. "Stuck black with a prompt" would probably mean that the local X11 display server crashed. If [these technical specifications for your laptop](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/thinkpad-t-series/ThinkPad-T470p/p/22TP2TT470P) are accurate, you have two GPUs: the Intel i7-7820HQ processor's integrated GPU (for power-efficiency), and a NVIDIA GeForce 940MX discrete GPU (for graphics performance when needed). The first question is, which one of them is actually being used to drive the display? What does `glxinfo | grep string` say?

Comment: My laptop is T470S that's the specs:

**CPU:** Intel i5-6300U (4) @ 3.000GHz 
**GPU:** Intel Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520]

[here](https://pastebin.com/V6W4Snpk) the output for `glxinfo | grep string`.